# Variable Append Java

Tags: java, eclipse, arff

I'm using Java to code Data Mining application.
To do so I'm reading a "arff" file and run it over a model created in WEKA.
Currently I have a ARFF file with one line as the data to process and its working good.

What i'm trying to achieve is: that user input from jCheckbox or something some information, and i'll use to to run on the model. I've taught of two ways to do it.
1. Read a file without the last line, and only append it directly to the variable.
2. Delete line number (same place always) from the ARFF, build a line from user inputs, write it to ARFF, and then read the ARFF again.

Any suggestion on which (I think 1 is better) and in general how ?
Tried some code with StringBuilder but no success.

Comment: Show us your code ...